# Material UI Dark Mode

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I am trying to implement dark mode, and I thought the Paper component was needed from Material UI to do so. Anyway, I've been having problems since it's doing the opposite: it won't work with Paper, and I cannot even remove it since other Material UI components use it. The only "fix" I found is applying

```
.MuiPaper-root {
  color: unset !important;
  background-color: unset !important;
}
```

to the Paper component, which doesn't solve anything since it then messes with other components. Am I missing something? This is my _app.js

```
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Paper sx={{ marginLeft: '250px' }} elevation={0}>
                    <Layout onGetTheme={getTheme}>
                        <main>
                            <Head>
                                <title>page</title>
                                <link
                                    rel="stylesheet"
                                    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
                                />
                                <meta
                                    name="viewport"
                                    content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width"
                                />
                            </Head>
                            <Component {...pageProps} />

                            <Footer></Footer>
                        </main>
                    </Layout>
                </Paper>
            </Provider>
        </ThemeProvider>
    </StyledEngineProvider>
```

**Theme code**

```
    const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState('light');
     const theme = useMemo(
    () =>
        createTheme({
            palette: {
                mode: darkMode,
            },
        }),
    [darkMode]
);
    const darkModeHandler = () => {
    setDarkMode(darkMode === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light');
};
```

**SCREENSHOTS**

This is how it is:

[image]
[image]

This is how it should be: (these last ones work when I apply `.MuiPaper-root { color: unset !important; background-color: unset !important; }` which messes up other components

[image]
[image]

Comment: You don't need to wrap your components with paper to use the dark mode, and you should add your theme code so we can check it.

Comment: @Abdulmuhaymin I added it. I tried removing Paper, but even so, other components I am using (like Cards) use it and it still messes with those

Comment: Have you tried the dark mode without `StyledEngineProvider`?

Comment: I have. Nothing changes. I don't have any customized theme or anything like that either

Comment: Can you show me your import code?

Comment: @NearHuscarl I mean I could, what would you need? I tried to take everything out but the dark mode and the material UI Cards and still won't work though so I am not sure

Comment: @FabioC I cannot reproduce the behavior you said with that snippet only. I need more context, specifically, my assumption is that you may import the component from v4 instead of v5 `material-ui/core` instead of `@mui/material`

Comment: @NearHuscarl not trying to be extra, but I think I love you. I spent legit an entire day on it lol. That was exactly the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MUI v5 changed a lot of thing, including the brand name (Material-UI to MUI). They moved the material components to a new package called `@mui/material`. If you happen to import the component from v4, then it won't work with emotion - the default styling engine that comes in v5. So check your import path:

```
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card'; // v4 - use JSS
```

```
import Card from '@mui/material/Card'; // v5 - use emotion by default
```